# Strange performance observed with memoized function

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, c++11

I was toying around with something that uses Euclid's algorithm to computed the GCD of two numbers.  I implemented the standard one-liner as usual, and it worked fine.  It's used in a algorithm that computes a series and calls `gcd()` several times per element as `n` gets larger.  I decided to see if I could do better by memoizing, so here is what I tried:

```
size_t const gcd(size_t const a, size_t const b) {
  return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}

struct memoized_gcd : private std::unordered_map<unsigned long long, size_t> {
  size_t const operator()(size_t const a, size_t const b) {
    unsigned long long const key = (static_cast<unsigned long long>(a) << 32) | b;
    if (find(key) == end()) (*this)[key] = b == 0 ? a : (*this)(b, a % b);
    return (*this)[key];
  }
};

//std::function<size_t (size_t, size_t)> gcd_impl = gcd<size_t,size_t>;
std::function<size_t (size_t, size_t)> gcd_impl = memoized_gcd();
```

I call the chosen function through the `std::function` instance later.  Interestingly, when for example n = 10,000, the calculation runs in 8 sec on this computer, and with the memoized version it's close to a minute, everything else being equal.

Have I missed something obvious?  I am using `key` as an expedient so that I don't need to specialize `std::hash` for the hash map.  The only things I can think of are maybe that the memoized version doesn't get the TCO and `gcd()` does, or that calling through the `std::function` is slow for the functor (even though I use it for both), or perhaps that I'm retarded.  Gurus, show me the way.

**Notes**

I've tried this on win32 and win64 with g++ 4.7.0 and linux x86 with g++ 4.6.1 and 4.7.1.

I also tried a version with a `std::map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, size_t>` that had comparable performance to the unmemoized version.

Comment: You might wanna have a good look at the memory usage of the memorized version. Once it slips out of cache, your hash-based random access is gonna hurt - really badly.

Comment: Euclid's algorithm bounces around so much in complexity for different values of a and b...I get the feeling that the worst case inputs for gcd are generally not in the cache, but I thought the other inputs would get some benefit from memoization.  I guess I'm the only one surprised by the difference in timing I observed.

Comment: `static_cast<unsigned long long>(a) << 32` is basically nonsensical -- on x64, `size_t` is typically already a typedef for `unsigned long long`, so you're just discarding bits. Also, show the full code for your actual benchmark (including your highest value for `n`); that's just as likely to be wrong as this.

Comment: Good point, that was quickly done on x86 where I originally saw the behavior, so it's actually pretty surprising that the rest of the program gives correct results on x64. There is no rigorous benchmark, just what I considered to be odd behavior.  Like I said in the question, I've mostly tested this with n = 10000...and on x86 where that statement is *not* nonsensical, the disparity in running times is even greater, although there are surely other unconsidered factors.

Comment: ...er, I mean, no, it's not nonsensical at all, I can afford to shift out those bits in this example because I'm dealing with relatively small values of a and b, which are strictly <= n.  Either way, it's just an expedient for an experiment.

Comment: The tail recursion of the gcd algorithm can be optimized to a small loop, with just a couple of variables on machine registers. GCC uis probably optimizing the recursion out. Even with doing integer divisions, it's likely faster than the multiple memory lookups and allocations from the memoized version. Just try counting how many iterations/recursions your gcd() function does.

Comment: @keith.layne : Code is either sensible for all inputs or not at all. You didn't tell us what values of `n` you were using, how should we know that it was always small and to ignore errors in the code thusly?

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.  Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: I'd call this a pretty definitive answer: for n = 5000, cache hits: 1,229,749, cache misses: 3,103,347. I guess it's just not worth it. Maybe it would be interesting to limit what was cached and see if I got anything out of it, but I'm getting bored.

Comment: @keith.layne: I would also note that you always look-up *twice* on the `unordered_map` (since you don't cache the result of `find(key)`), while the second look-up (`return ...`) does not involve cache misses (normally) it still takes its own toll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue with your version of GCD is that it may use up huge amounts of memory, depending on the usage pattern.

For example, if you compute GCD(a,b) for all pairs 0 <= a < 10,000, 0 <= b < 10,000, the memoization table will end up with 100,000,000 entries. Since on x86 each entry is 12 bytes, the hash table will take up at least 1.2 GB of memory. Working with that amount of memory is going to be slow.

And of course, if you evaluate GCD with values >=10,000, you can make the table arbitrarily large... at least until you run out of the address space or the commit limit.

**Summary**: In general, memoizing GCD is a bad idea because it leads to unbounded memory usage.

There are some finer points that could be discussed:

- As the table exceeds various sizes, it will be stored in slower and slower memory: first L1 cache, then L2 cache, L3 cache (if present), physical memory, disk. Obviously the cost of the memoization increases dramatically as the table grows.
- If you know that all inputs are in a small range (e.g., 0 <= x < 100), using memoization or a precomputed table could still be an optimization. Hard to be sure - you'd have to measure in your particular scenario.
- There are potentially other ways of optimizing GCD. E.g., I am not sure whether g++ automatically recognizes tail recursion in this example. If not, you could get a performance boost by rewriting the recursion into a loop.

But as I said, it is not surprising at all that the algorithm you posted does not perform well.

Comment: I didn't mention, but this was based off of building with -O3.  I assume that the recursion is getting the tail call optimization in the simple version.  My requirement is only for small values of n, but I wanted to see if I could calculate bigger values more efficiently.  Interestingly, when I changed my strategy to cache only when a and b are less than 256 and use a vector of unsigned char, performance is indistinguishable for n = {5000, 10000, 20000}.  It looks like the cost of memory access for small a and b pretty much balances the cost of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't that surprising. On modern CPUs, memory access is very slow, especially if it is not in the cache. It's often faster to recompute a value than to store it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Frequent heap allocation (when creating new entries). Also std::unordered_map lookup overhead (while it might be constant time, it is certainly slower than an plain array offset). Cache misses also (a function of access pattern and size).

If you want to do a "pure" comparison, you  can try converting it to use a static, stack-allocated plain array; this might be a sparse lookup table that uses more memory, but it will be more representative of memoization **iff** you can fit the entire memoized array into your CPU cache.